# Calling jest.clearAllMocks() in beforeEach clears calls within a test?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I'm seeing an issue in Jest where calling `jest.clearAllMocks()` inside a `beforeEach` callback seems to wipe out calls to a mocked function that are made not before but WITHIN a specific test.  I can repro it as follows:

THIS PASSES:

#### `__tests__/testy.test.js`

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const { handler } = require("../index.js");

describe("Lambda function tests", () => {
    it("sent the expected CSV data to S3", async () => {
        // RUN THE LAMBDA, await completion
        await handler();
        // The S3 constructor should have been called during Lambda execution
        expect(AWS.S3).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

THIS GIVES ME A FAILURE:

#### `__tests__/testy.test.js`

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const { handler } = require("../index.js");

describe("Lambda function tests", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });
    it("sent the expected CSV data to S3", async () => {
        // RUN THE LAMBDA, await completion
        await handler();
        // The S3 constructor should have been called during Lambda execution
        expect(AWS.S3).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The failure message in the console:

```sh
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

I'm using jest version 27.4.3 in Node v14.18.1. In case it matters, I'm mocking `aws-sdk` like this:

#### `__mocks__/aws-sdk.js`

```js
const AWS = jest.createMockFromModule("aws-sdk");

AWS.S3 = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    upload: jest.fn(() => ({ promise: jest.fn() })),
    headObject: jest.fn(() => ({
        promise: jest.fn(() => ({ ContentLength: 123 })),
    })),
}));

module.exports = AWS;
```

What could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by restructuring my main code.  Previously I was instantiating `S3` outside of the `handler` function:

#### `index.js`

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const S3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async () => {
    S3.upload({ ... });
}
```

Now I'm doing it this way, and the problem is resolved:

#### `index.js`

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = async () => {
    const S3 = new AWS.S3();
    S3.upload({ ... });
}
```

In hindsight, it makes sense. `index.js` is run before `beforeEach` executes, not each time a test is run.